# Is it adding fragments to ArrayList is bad for performance?

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist

Here I am adding some `Fragment`s to `List` in a static method.

```
public static List<Fragment> TOOLS(){
        List<Fragment> fragments=new ArrayList<>();
        fragments.add(new SubjectFragment());
        fragments.add(new ExamFragment());
        fragments.add(new AdminToolsFragment());
        return fragments;
    }
```

I am using this is because of my conveniences.
Early I used switch statement

```
switch (textView.getId()) {
            case R.id.subject:
                onButtonPressed(new SubjectFragment(), "Subject");
                break;
            case R.id.exam:
                onButtonPressed(new ExamFragment(), "exam");
                break;
            case R.id.tools:
                onButtonPressed(new AdminToolsFragment(), "adminTools");
                break;
}
```

Now instead of switch statement I used its position with `List`.
Like this.

```
fragments.get(position);
```

My question is arise when creating fragment objects

```
new MyFragment();
```

ie. Creating more and more instances is expensive. So in switch statement there is only **one instance** created at a time. But when using list

```
    fragments.add(new SubjectFragment());
    fragments.add(new ExamFragment());
    fragments.add(new AdminToolsFragment());
```

**Many instances** are created at a time.

Question is.
 **Is it adding fragments to list is bad for performance? if it is no then what is the reason?**

Answer (score 0):

I think no, because of if You have a lot of different fragments you SHOULD use ArrayList for fast access for each item. Until You have couple fragments there is no difference between them.

p.s. If I understand right when using fragments with same structure use newInstance method, if no - there only way create new one object.

Comment: when using switch only one object is created.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is suggested that we should reduce creating unused objects as much as possible. That too in memory constraint platforms like mobiles it is highly recommended to follow that.

Here you are creating two unused `Fragment` object and one `List` object which can be avoided. Using switch will not make any big difference in performance since it has only a few cases. So in your case, using switch is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use FragmentManager, when you show a fragment, you could add a tag for it

```
Fragment newFragment = new FunnyFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.requestContainer, newFragment, "YOU_TAG_NAME");
        transaction.addToBackStack(FunnyFragment.class.getSimpleName());
        transaction.commit();
```

when you need get that fragment again, just call:

```
FunnyFragment funnyFragment = (FunnyFragment)getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentByTag("YOU_TAG_NAME");
```

Comment: I am using this already. I'm just passing fragments to `FragmentTransaction`'s `replace()` method

Comment: you can check if(funnyFragment!=null) when findFragmentByTag . If null, create new one, if not null , USE it.

Comment: Thank you. But seriously I know that..:)